# asp.net post action error on retrofit calling but okey on manual calling

Tags: android, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, retrofit

I am using asp.net webapi v2 to create a rest api, everything is OK ! the GET request handled well, but I have a problem with POST request. I write a POST method in the Controller, and can call it using Postman. But when I try to call POST request with retrofit in my android app, it fails and get me this error : 405 Method Not Allowed.

It seems that every thing is okey but I don't know whats the problem !

this is my retrofit rest service :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Report")
void sendReport(@Field("UniqueID") String UniqueID, @Field("ShopID") long ShopID, @Field("Content") String Content, Callback<Boolean> callback);
```

I should mention that I've return bool in my POST action ! can it cause the problem because of Boolean in the retrofit ?!

what should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, but I don't know why this happened !
The problem was the URL endpoint, It seems that POST method in webapi are case sensitive and I should use report against Report !!! (That was not happen in GET cases)

Another problem was the www prefix ! when I remove that it works like a charm but again it doesn't matter in GET cases !!!

I post this answer to help someone with the similar case ... hope so.